# Do non-Thunderbolt monitors work with a DVI-D adapter on a Thunderbolt MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a [MacBook Pro (15-inch, Early 2011)](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp620). I want to hook two Dell monitors to it. They have VGA and DVI ports each.

I will be using the current DVI port on the MacBook Pro.

Will the Thunderbolt port work with a non-Thunderbolt monitor if I find a Thunderbolt to DVI-D adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same MBP.  It only has a single displayport/thunderbolt output, which can drive a single monitor.  The only way for it to drive multiple external displays is to use a daisy chained Thunderbolt display, or an adapter that drives multiple displays from a single input (Matrox makes one) or possibly a usb driven adapter.

Comment: is there nothing like a Thunderbolt to DVI adapter? plain and simple.

Comment: Yes, you can drive a single external monitor using a DVI or VGA adapter.  But not two.